# Is it possible to run Facebook application on mulitple domains?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cross-site

I've one Facebook application, that I want to use on domainA.com and domainB.com.

The only problem is, that if I've set application domain in the facebook settings to domainA.com, it doesn't work on domainB.com - is there a way to say to Facebook, that my application needs to work on ALL domains (it's dynamic created which domains my script will run on).

Hope it makes sense and you have a nice solution! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to implement a "proxy" server that lives on one domain.  All requests from the other domains will need to be filtered thru the "proxy" server.  Think of your proxy server like a Single Sign On server if that helps you understand the paradigm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Here is a workaround for the scenario you are describing:

On the Basic Settings page for your app, in the Basic Info section in the App Domain field enter both domainA.com and domainB.com.  ALSO in the "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" section, for the Website Site URL, enter http://domainA.com and under the Mobile Web section, for the Mobile Web URL, enter http://domainB.com.